# Scheduling events when time is a floating point value

Tags: python, floating-point, scheduling, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision

The following example highlights a pitfall with regard to the use of floating point numbers:

```
available_again = 0
for i in range(0,15):
   time = 0.1*i

   if time < available_again:
      print("failed to schedule at " + str(time))

   available_again = time + 0.1
```

This code outputs the following:

```
failed to schedule at 1.3
```

I wasn't expecting this error however I do understand why it occurs. What options have I in order to address this problem?

One fix in my code would be:

```
available_again = 0.1*(i+1)
```

I'm wondering if this is the correct route. My particular application involves the scheduling of events where the time at which events occur is dictated by complex mathematical functions, for example: sinc(2*pi*f*t). The duration of events will be such that events may overlap each other, in which case I will need to send them on separate channels.

Comment: May sound obvious, but I think the only reliable way to do that is using integers (and set the unit to milliseconds, microseconds or whatever). Maybe you can scale your complex timestamps and use them as integers (like `int(1000*sin(2*pi*f*t)`)?

Answer (score 1):

> One fix in my code would be:
>
> available_again = 0.1*(i+1)

This fix is correct and will make your code work as long as `time` remains small enough for the floating-point resolution to be better than 0.1 (up to about 2<sup>50</sup>).

It works because the floating-point number `0.1*(i+1)` computed at iteration `i` is **exactly the same** as the floating-point number computed as `0.1*i` with `i` having been incremented by one at the next iteration, and because as long as integers `n` and `m` remain lower than about 2<sup>50</sup>, no two `0.1*n` and `0.1*m` are equal for different values of `n` and `m`.

The reason is that floating-point arithmetic is deterministic. The floating-point operation `0.1 * n` may produce a counter-intuitive result for some integral values of `n`, but it always produces the same result for the same `n`.

---

If in addition it is important for you that `time` is the closest possible the mathematical quotient i / 10, then you should compute `time` as `i / 10.0`, and logically, compute `available_again` as `(i+1) / 10.0`.

This continues to work for the same reason as above, and it has the additional property always to compute the floating-point number nearest to the intended quotient, whereas `0.1 * i` magnifies the representation error between the floating-point number `0.1` and the rational 1/10.

In neither case will two consecutive values of `time` always be separated by the same interval. With the `i/10.0` computation, the floating-point value with float around the rational i/10. With `0.1*i`, it will float around i*0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. If you have the freedom to pick the sampling frequency, choose it so that the factor between `i` and `time` is a power of two (say 1/64 or 1/128). Then you will have the additional property that `time` is computed exactly and that every time interval is exactly the same.